# Array number/position in custom Laravel validation messages

Tags: laravel, validation

When validating arrays in Laravel and using custom error messages, is there any way to access the array number/position that is throwing the validation failure?

Trying to manipulate :attribute or :key in the messages array of the Request doesn't work as the placeholders are later translated (read: they aren't the actual variables)

I am trying to present a message like:

```
object.property.*.required => 'The property on object # is required'
```

Otherwise you end up with something like:

```
object.property.3 is required
```

I'd like to grab the number so I can present a friendlier and more descriptive message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this can be achieved by the **`replacer`** method on the  **`Validator`** facade. Add the `replacer` in **`AppServiceProvider@boot`** method.

```
//...

public function boot()
{           
    Validator::replacer('required', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
        if (str_contains($message, ':nth') && preg_match("/\.(\d+)\./", $attribute, $match)) {
            return str_replace(":nth", $match[1]+ 1, $message);
        }

        return $message;
    });
}

//...
```

The custom validation message for the attribute must contain the palceholder **`:nth`**

```
object.property.*.required => 'The property on object :nth is required'
```

Comment: Thank you! If I wanted to have this work for 'min' or other validator rules would I have to duplicate this for each rule or is there a way to follow DRY?

Comment: According to the current version of Laravel, yes, you have to repeat this for each rules.

Comment: Thank you again =D